# Installing a PhoneGap plugin - BarcodeScanner

Tags: cordova, barcode-scanner

```
$ phonegap version
3.2.0-0.16.0
```

I have been through all the documentation and can't find out what is going on here. Steps I have completed so far:

1. Installed the plugin through Plugman:

   `plugman install --platform ios --project platforms/ios/ --plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner.git`

   I can now see the plugin installed in /app/dir/platforms/ios/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
2. Added the plugin code to my config.xml

   `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />`
3. Tried viewing `window.plugins` and `cordova.plugins` in my console after DeviceReady has been fired. Both are undefined
4. I also tried including the JS in my index.html (which I was sure you don't have to do as this is completed as part of the build process) and then repeated step 3. but no luck.

Comment: Can you add the code of how you include the js files? The order of files are important.

Comment: I was including my third party libraries first, like backbone and jquery. Then phonegap.js, then barcodescanner.js, then app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the barcodescanner has support for PG 3.2.0 yet, if it has you can check the following. (https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/68)

If plugins are correctly installed they should automatically update your res/xml/config.xml :

`<feature name="BarcodeScanner">

<param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
</feature>`

Check if your plugins are correctly installed by searching for them via `plugman search` command.

If not, you could try and install the plugin like this :

`phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner.git`

Comment: I restarted my project from scratch and installed the plugin using plugin local add, this seemed to fix it.